# Problema con envió de información a base de datos online, Android Studio

Tags: php, javascript, android-studio, base-de-datos

Hola a todos como estan?

Tengo un problema con una aplicación que estoy desarrollando, les resumo el funcionamiento de ella, se trata de una aplicacion la cual escanea un codigo de barras y ese codigo lo verifica el usuario y lo confirma para luego ser enviado, el cual se almacena en una base de datos online en esta caso usando el hosting de 000webhost.com

En las versiones de Android studio inferiores a la 3.0.0 funciona perfectamente como esta, ahora que se a actualizado no se que sucede pero solo registra el primer valor y los demas siguientes que se escanea no los registra.

En la ventana de "RUN" cuando el primer valor se envía indica esto:
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Les comparto parte del codigo donde se obtiene el valor escaneado y se pega en un textView, ese valor de ese textview es el que se envia a la base de datos online

```
 public class ScalingScannerActivity extends BaseScannerActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler, View.OnClickListener {
    private static final String FLASH_STATE = "FLASH_STATE";

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    private boolean mFlash;
    private TextView pastetext;
    private Button btnverificar,btnregistrar,btnregresar;
    String copied2;
    int camera=0;



@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scaling_scanner);

        ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);


        copied2 = "Escanea algo";

        pastetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pastetext);
        btnverificar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnverificar);
        btnregresar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregresar);
        btnregistrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnregistrar);

            btnverificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pastetext.setText(copied2);

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "¿Estas seguro de que estos son los datos?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    btnregistrar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   /*btnnewscan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    btnregistrar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    scanBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/

                }
            });


            btnregresar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ScalingScannerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

//En esta parte se inicia el envio de la informacion obtenida

```
            btnregistrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Registrando...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    String qr = pastetext.getText().toString();
                    //btnregistrar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



                    Response.Listener <String> respoListener = new Response.Listener <String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                                if (success){
                                    //Intent intent=new Intent(ScalingScannerActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                   // ScalingScannerActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Registro satisfactorio" +response , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show();

                                }else{
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScalingScannerActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("error al registrar")
                                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                            .create().show();
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Error al Registar ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    RegisterRequest registerRequest=new RegisterRequest(qr,respoListener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ScalingScannerActivity.this);
                    queue.add(registerRequest);

                }



                });
            }






    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        // You can optionally set aspect ratio tolerance level
        // that is used in calculating the optimal Camera preview size
        mScannerView.setAspectTolerance(0.2f);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
        mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(FLASH_STATE, mFlash);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(final com.google.zxing.Result rawResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Contents = " + rawResult.getText() +
                ", Format = " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();

        String item = rawResult.toString();
        copied2 = item;
        // Note:
        // * Wait 2 seconds to resume the preview.
        // * On older devices continuously stopping and resuming camera preview can result in freezing the app.
        // * I don't know why this is the case but I don't have the time to figure out.
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScalingScannerActivity.this);


            }
        }, 5000);




    }










    public void toggleFlash(View v) {
        mFlash = !mFlash;
        mScannerView.setFlash(mFlash);
    }



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
```

}}

El codigo anterior llama a esta clase RegisterRequest la cual se encarga de tomar el dato escaneado y enviarlo a la base de datos

les dejo el codigo de esa clase

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="https://nombreprivado.000webhostapp.com/..../RegistrarQR.php";
private Map<String,String>params;
public RegisterRequest(String qr, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener, null);
    params=new HashMap<>();
    params.put("qr",qr);



}

@Override
public Map<String,String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

}

en el archivo php almacenado en el hosting esta de esta manera

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "nombre basededatos");

$qr = $_POST["qr"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Asistencias (qr) VALUES (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $qr);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  


echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

en lo cual este archivo php funciona sin problemas

e probado varios archivos php y en todos pasa la misma historia, solo permite el envió del primer dato escaneado, el segundo ya no los envía y no muestra ningún error

como les decía cuando se envía el primer dato en la ventana "run" aparece esto

D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

después de que escaneo otro y le doy enviar, ya no indica nada en la ventana run

espero me puedan ayudar, lo necesito urgente.

por cierto, ya probe creando un archivo de configuracion de red "networkSecurityConfig"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>


</base-config>
```

lo probe de esa manera incluso dejando solo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        </base-config>
```

y tambien

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<base-config >

</base-config>
```

dejando el archivo sin configuracion lo unico que sucede es que en la ventana run indica que se tomo ese archivo de configuracion correctamente, pero el problema sigue igual, solo envia el primer dato escaneado y los demas no envia, toca cerrar toda la aplicacion para volver a enviar otro dato.